# how to open expression window in darteditor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I can't seem to find the option to display the expressions window while debugging.

As seen [here](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/#features), there should be a tab called expressions.

I can't find any option nor any symbol that looks like it on my machine (Windows 7 64-bit, Dart/sdk/editor 0.5.*** 32 bit).

I can't find anything on Google or Stack Overflow and I have been searching for over a day now. What am I missing?

Comment: FYI I opened https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11660 to track the update to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those docs need to be updated - we removed the expressions editor a while ago. It's going to be replaced with an object inspector, which will be more full featured and have a better UX.

Comment: Thank you ^^ cant wait for it!